# How can we add an AlertDialog to this bloc?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i want to add an AlertDialog when a call is received(SIP application) and i'm really confused of how to add this in this bloc:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
        try {

            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    try {
                        call.answerCall(30);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            SIPCommunicator wtActivity = (SIPCommunicator) context;

            incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            incomingCall.answerCall(30);
            incomingCall.startAudio();
            incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
            if(incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                incomingCall.toggleMute();
            }

            wtActivity.call = incomingCall;

            wtActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you cant have alertdialog inside onRecieve

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: I think you can launch an activity using proper intent and then show the alter dialog inside the activity

Comment: like this Intent monIntent = new Intent(this,dialog.class);
            startActivity(monIntent); ??????

Comment: now start an activity using the intent and show the dialog inside the activity.

Comment: I added this in the manifest to show the dialog activity as a dialog : "@android:style/Theme.Dialog".